# How do I add a User Input of type String to an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I am attempting to make a course registration system and one of my classes (Course) is centered around course attributes (ie. Course number, course name, instructors, students). I am making an ArrayList so that the Administrator (one of the user types) may add as many instructors to the course as he/she would like- I have created a Scanner and a String variable and everything, but when I write the .add command, Eclipse highlights ".add" and says "the method .add() is undefined for the type of scanner". Now, I can understand this, but I have no idea how to fix it and I've tried so many ideas.

Here is the method:`

```
public static String Instructor(){
        String courseInstructors;

        System.out.println("Please add name(s) of course instructors.");
        ArrayList<String> Instructors= new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner courseInst = new Scanner(System.in);
        courseInstructors = courseInst.next();
        //courseInst.add(courseInstructors); 

        for(String courseInstructors1 : Instructors) {
            courseInstructors1 = courseInstructors;
            courseInst.add(courseInstructors1);
        }

        return;
    }`
```

Comment: I think you meant to call `add` on `Instructors`, not `courseInst`. Either way, you should name the reference `instructors`, not `Instructors`.

Comment: The `for(String courseInstructors1 : Instructors)` doesn't make sense to me. Since you just created the `Instructors` collection, it is empty and there will be no iterations. What is the purpose of this loop? What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please adhere to Java naming conventions ad use lower case for variable names - `instructors` instead of `Instructors`.

Also, you want to add to your arraylist, so call `add()` on

```
instructors.add(courseInstructors1)
```

You may also want to consider choosing better variable naming than `courseInstructors1`, for instance just `courseInstructor`, since you are referring to on `instructor` of all `instructors`.

Also in your for loop you are doing the following

```
for(String courseInstructors1 : Instructors) {
    courseInstructors1 = courseInstructors;
    courseInst.add(courseInstructors1);
}
```

This can be simplified to

```
for(String courseInstructors1 : Instructors) {
    courseInst.add(courseInstructors);
}
```

And if you look at the simplification you will see that iterating through Instructors make no sense here, since you are not using the contents of courseInstructors1.

Comment: I named the variable courseInstructors1 because i needed to define a new String in the for loop (i dont know why). It was not allowing me just use courseInstructors, so i just set them equal to eachother to get around it. annoying, but its all I could think of. Do you know of any other ways to get around that?

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm obviously fairly new to Java, so this WOULD be an effective way to go about this, right? (with the for loop) I just want the user to be able to enter multiple instructors for the course.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to understand what your loop is for.

if you are trying to get multiple instructor names from one input then you need something like this.

```
//get input
//"John Peggy Adam blah blah"
courseInstructors = courseInst.next();

//split the string by white space
String[] instArr = courseInstructors.split(" ");
//will give array of John, Peggy, Adam, blah, blah
```

Then do your foreach loop to add them to the list.

```
for(String inst: instArr){
    instructors.add(inst);
}
```

Otherwise I would suggest doing something like this so you don't have to worry about splitting names and such.

```
courseInstructor = courseInst.nextLine();

while(!courseInstructor.equals("done"){
    //add name to list of instructors.
    instructors.add(courseInstructor);
    //get next name.
    courseInstructor = courseInt.nextLin();
    //if the user types done, it will break the loop.
    //otherwise come back around and add it and get next input.
}
```

Comment: the function of my for loop is to allow the user to enter multiple names. For example, the user would add "Paul" then *click enter*; he would then add "James" *click enter* and it would add to the arraylist over and over again.

Comment: That is what i figured you wanted but I wasn't sure. Then what you would need is what i posted at the bottom.

Comment: something like it anyways.